# Могут ли быть однородными сказуемыми глаголы разных видов?

Tags: запятые

Нуждаюсь в квалифицированной помощи, что-то голова совсем не варит! Предложение "Крупный склад станков, приезжайте и проверьте товар перед отгрузкой." Могут ли быть однородными сказуемыми глаголы разных видов? Или корректно "приезжайте и проверяйте"? Или пропущена запятая после "приезжайте"?

Answer (score 1):

Что касается запятой, то она не нужна. Вот пример из Розенталя, главы про сложносочиненные: ‟Подпустить врага и огонь дать по команде!” Не знаю, считаются ли такие сказуемые однородными одного предложения или сказуемыми разных с сложносочиненной связью. Я бы поставил на первое.
Что касается возможности оставить одно такое сказуемое несовершенным, а другое совершенным. Никто не может запретить нам сказать, чтобы одно действие делали, а другое сделали, — или наоборот. Например: ‟Иди и купи молока”, ‟Ешь торт, но не съешь весь” и т.д. Никто не может какой-либо нормой запретить такую возможность в языке.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! А то я уже в собственных знаниях сомневаться начала. Ум за разум заходит после написания большого количества текста.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Фраза "Крупный склад станков, приезжайте и проверьте товар перед отгрузкой" построена не как обращение к потенциальному покупателю, а как предложение какому-то Складу сняться с места и приехать для проверки товара.
Возможно, что Вам хотелось сказать: «Здесь крупный склад станков. Приезжайте и воспользуйтесь возможностью проверить товар перед отгрузкой!».
В таком случае, запятую после слова «станков» лучше заменить точкой. Что касается запятой между двух сказуемых, то она не нужна, ее  с успехом заменяет собой союз «и».